# Looping name backwards in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

I want to print my name backwards from n times (n = 1-100). I can't seem to figure it out. As you can see by my code, the strrev() does not work when looping as it constantly reverses over and over again. I would also like to somehow enforce the user to enter a letter and not number for name, but that is not as imperative.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main () 
{
    int choice;
    char name[255];
    int loopCounter;
    int count;
    int number;

    do 
    {
        printf("1.Display Your Name\n");
        printf("2.Display Your Name (From 1-100)\n");
        printf("3.Display your Name Backwards\n");
        printf("4.Display Your Name Backwards (From 1-100)\n");
        printf("5.Quit\n");

        printf("Enter your name:\n");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("Enter your choice:   ");
        scanf("%i", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
                printf("Your name is %s.\n", name);
                break;
            case 2:  
                printf("How many times to display your name? (1-100) ");
                scanf("%i", &count);

                if ( 100 < count) 
                {
                    printf("Please enter 1 through 100\n");
                }
                else 
                {
                    loopCounter = 0;
                    while (loopCounter < count ) 
                    {
                        loopCounter++;
                        printf("%d %s\n", loopCounter,name);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Your name backwards is: %s\n\n", strrev(name));
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("How many times to display your name backwards? ");
                scanf("%i", &count);
                if ( 100 < count) 
                {
                    printf("Please enter 1 through 100\n");
                }
                else 
                {
                    loopCounter = 0;
                    while (loopCounter < count ) 
                    {
                        loopCounter++;
                        printf("%d %s\n", loopCounter, strrev(name));
                    }
                }
                break;
           case 5:
               printf("Goodbye!!!!\n");
               break;
           default:
               printf("Was not 1 through 5\n");
               break;
       }
   } while (choice!=5);
}
```

Comment: Is your text editor an angry cat?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `strrev()` reverses the string in place.

If you want to keep the original, you should make a copy of name and use `strrev()` to reverse it once, before the loop. Then in the loop, just call the reversed name.

Otherwise, just do this:

```
loopCounter = 0;
strrev(name);
while (loopCounter < count ) {
    loopCounter++;
    printf("%d %s\n", loopCounter, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution where there is not requirement of `strrev`.. Watch the following code:--
main()

```
{
char name[255];
int loopcounter;
  for(loopcounter = strlen(name)-1; loopcounter>=0; loopcounter--)
  {
     printf("%c", name[loopcounter]);
  }
}
```

This code will definitely help you....ok